# Tracking custom event with Google Analytics by Yoast Plugin for WordPress

Tags: jquery, plugins, google-analytics, wordpress

Hey guys can anyone help me out about how to do custom even tracking while using [Yoast Analytics plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)? I'm adding custom code via jquery depending on adblcoking enabled like this

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Adblock', 'Blocked', 'false',,true])`

but it didn't worked and showed me `_gaq.push` not defined. Now as I have enabled Universal Tracking within the plugin and read a lot on google I also tried the following:

`__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Adblock', 'Blocked');`

Guess what, it didn't worked either. I tried to contact the plugin dev, no answer from there too. So, I'm hoping if someone has tried this before be and get succeeded, might help me out on this.

Here are the screenshot of my Yoast Analytics Plugin Settings page if you need it to help me out.

This is my universal tab - http://puu.sh/kzLnj/570ba6e165.png

This is my advanced tab - http://puu.sh/kzLqr/205239bdfd.png

Can anybody truly help me out on this?

P.S.: I've also tried the following:

`ga('send', 'event', 'Adblock', 'Blocked');`

It didn't worked either.

Comment: the _gaq function is only for classic GA. If you are using UA, then you need to use the "ga" functions. What error message are you getting with the "ga" functions? Did you check that the hits are going through either in Real-Time or with GA Debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'lead', 'click', ' contact');
```

use:

```
__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'lead', 'click', ' contact');
```

Here is more info: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/note-change-of-global-function-ga-_gatracker